# django-tenants postgis with multischema

Tags: python, django, postgis, multi-tenant, django-tenants

How can i install postgis extension for 2 shema? shema_1 and shema_2,
my commands:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shema_1 AUTHORIZATION admin;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shema_2 AUTHORIZATION admin;
SET search_path = shema_1, shema_2, public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
```

Its install only for `shema_1`,
and command
`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA schema_2;`
says `postgis already exists`.
In `settings.py` set  `ORIGINAL_BACKEND = "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"`